# Is it smart to make navigation menu as a separate controller - asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Currently I have a page with navigation menu. This navigation menu get it items and sub items from database.
I think that it would be easier for me to control it if I make it as a separate controller.
For example:

```
public class NavigationMenu : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Menu()
    {
        Model model = // Get items and sub items
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Is this right way to make this or I shouldn't do this from some reason?

And if I make it this Menu view will not have any master layout. Should I remove all `<html><head><body>...` html code from it or not?

Comment: I would suggest using a Partial View and using Html.Partial to render a partial view OR look in to creating a custom Html Helper with will allow you to render the menu.

Comment: I can't make it as partial because menu get items from database. So it has it's own Model.

Comment: Thats the difference between Html.Partial and Html.RenderPartial. Like I said, you can also build your own Html Helper that can get them from the database and cache the output.

Comment: @Splash-X, a HTML Helper is not the correct place to connect to a database.

Comment: If you are connecting to a database to return a static list of data that won't change for a period of time there is no reason a Html Helper can't connect to a database

Comment: Html.RenderAction is probably a better design idea here ... that call can be placed in the layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use this pattern, though we call it NavigationController, and the action method is TopTabs. We have it as a [ChildActionOnly], and return a partial view. To render the navigation in the layout, we use @Html.Action().

I'd answer your question with a yes, and render the partial view as a child action in either your layout or your main views:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public class NavigationController : Controller
{
    public PartialViewResult CommonMenu()
    {
        Model model = // Get items and sub items
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what that ChildActionOnly attribute do?

Comment: From : http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx "This attribute indicates that this action should not be callable directly via the URL."